# Running this example the output is always 1. It seems that the C++ polymorphism is not working?

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I am learning C++ and faced this quiz test. Why the output is always 1?
Why the polymorphism is not working? The methods calculate os classes MyClassTwo and MyClassThree are not called.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyClassOne {
public:
    int calculate() { return 1; }
};
class MyClassTwo : public MyClassOne {
public:
    virtual int calculate() { return 2; }
};
class MyClassThree : public MyClassTwo {
public:
    int calculate() { return 3; }
};
int main() {
    int result = 0;
    MyClassOne* objs[3];
    objs[0] = new MyClassOne();
    objs[1] = new MyClassTwo();
    objs[2] = new MyClassThree();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        cout << objs[i]->calculate() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make `calculate` virtual in the base class `MyClassOne`.

Comment: the baseclass doesn't have the `calculate` function virtual....

Comment: Instead of `virtual int calculate() { return 2; }` you should have `int calculate()  override { return 2; }` and make the base function `virtual int calculate() { return 1; }`. Using `override` in the derived class will help you from making this mistake and other mistakes like having different signatures.

Comment: @drescherjm its a quiz test, so not a typo but on purpose.

Comment: You are correct. I was not the one that voted to close as a typo but thought of it. I did not read the question yet. I usually do a review of the code before looking at the question.

Comment: @drescherjm same here and I was too hastily with voting as typo. Btw not proud of the answer either, its not more than a spoiler of the quiz

Answer (score 2):

`MyClassOne::calculate` is not `virtual`:

```
class MyClassOne {
public:
    int calculate() { return 1; }
};
```

Hence, if you call `calculate` on a `MyClassOne*` what is called is that method, not something else.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

The static type of elements of the array `objs` is `MyClassOne*`

```
MyClassOne* objs[3];
```

So in this expression:

```
objs[i]->calculate()
```

The name calculate is searched in the class `MyClassOne`. In this class there is a declared non-virtual function calculate:

```
class MyClassOne {
public:
    int calculate() { return 1; }
};
```

That is called for each pointed object. Maybe you mean

```
class MyClassOne {
public:
    virtual int calculate() { return 1; }
};
```